# Ctrl-C'd an in-place recursive gzip - is this likely to have broken anything?

Tags: linux, command-line, gzip

So, today i was trying to zip up a large folder (that has a large nested set of subfolders), in linux. I did:

```
gzip -r bigfolder bigfolder.gz
```

and after it had been going for a couple of minutes I realised that this wouldn't make a single big gz file, but would instead individually zip, in place, every file (but not directory) within `bigfolder`. So, I <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd>'d it.

Then, I realised that I'd also got the syntax wrong (one of those days): I thought the second argument would be where it was saved to, but it isn't: it's just going to do all the zipping in bigfolder in place.

So, I did:

```
gunzip -r bigfolder
```

and that seems to have turned it all back to normal. However, I'm worried that because i <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd>'d it, there might be a broken file in there, which had been halfway through getting zipped or something.

My understanding is that while <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>z</kbd> will just KILL it instantly, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> is a bit more "gentle" and more likely to let a small sub-process, like gzipping one of the individual files, finish before stopping. But, as you can probably guess, my understanding of these things isn't too precise.

I don't have a copy of bigfolder which I can `diff` against to see if it's broken.  Is it likely to be broken, do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First don't worry, your folder is not broken.

What you did with the first command is recusively gzip every file in the directory structure one by one. `gzip` will compress the file and remove the non-compressed one automatically (this is the default behaviour). However, while the compressing process, **both files will exists**.

Now, when you press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd>, the shell sends defaultly the signal [`SIGINT`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal#SIGINT) to the process which is running in the foreground. This signal can be caught by the running process, and therefore the process can handle that signal, as `gzip` does. `gzip` then has the prossibility to quit gracefully.

If you press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>z</kbd>, the shell sends normally the signal [`SIGTSTP`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal#SIGTSTP) which suspends (stops) the process. In case of `SIGTSTP`, `gzip` would also handle it, because it is also catchable.

You should not kill (`kill -9 <pid>`) the process, because that signal (`SIGKILL`) is not catchable by the process, and therefore `gzip` could not handle it. But even then, the original file would still be there.

**Conclusion:**

Let's assume `gzip` was compressing a huge file in that moment you pressed <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd>. As a result, `gzip` aborts the compression on that file it was working on and deletes the partially compressed file. Now, some files are gzipped, some not.

With `gunzip -r folder`, all files will be uncompressed back in their original state. The only problem could be if there were files in the original directory which **were** compressed; those are now uncompressed.

Comment: Great answer, in terms of explanation and also because it's the one i wanted to hear :) thanks!